# Using noSQL for storying data Realm

Tags: swift, database, core-data, realm

I'm creating an Iphone application and considering using realm for local storage. The application will basically fetch a few json files regarding prices on certain items and print of the price allocation for each item on each day.

I'm guessing that a traditional relational database for this will not work considering the columns for items is not fixed. In order words, on a certain day, there might be 10 items, next day 20.. etc.

Is my approach on using a noSQL database such as realm a good idea? Thanks

Comment: Good questions on StackOverflow (for which you will get meaningful answers) include some code you have written and ask a specific question about something your code fails to do. Open questions like this tend to be closed as being "opinionated".

Comment: `on a certain day, there might be 10 items, next day 20.. etc.` those are ***rows***